# An error occurred PutObject operation: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When start command:

```
aws --profile 1prof  --endpoint-url http://1.1.1.1:80 s3 --recursive cp /tmp/_out/1prof/tbl/ s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/
```

get errors:

```
upload: ./output-000005.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000005.csv
upload: ./output-000004.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000004.csv
upload: ./output-000002.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000002.csv
upload: ./output-000006.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000006.csv
upload: ./output-000007.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000007.csv
upload: ./output-000008.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000008.csv
upload: ./output-000009.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000009.csv
upload: ./output-000010.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000010.csv
upload failed: ./output-000003.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000003.csv An error occurred (XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.
upload failed: ./output-000001.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000001.csv An error occurred (XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.
upload failed: ./output-000011.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000011.csv An error occurred (XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.
upload failed: ./output-000012.csv to s3://1prof/tbl/tbl20231025/output-000012.csv An error occurred (XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.
```

Please help me what am I doing wrong

Comment: `CompleteMultipartUpload` - is your internet connection stable? This is an intermittent issue, please retry,.

Comment: yes, internet connection stable.

Comment: Have you retried?